# VB.Net, Problem updating table from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

This is my first post so forgive me if I goof!
I am trying to update myself from VBA to VB.Net. Using loads of help from Google etc I am doing Ok except when I try to update my table from a DataGridView. It just does not update. What I would like is that a cell is update on change. My code so far is shown (I have tried all sorts of builder, tables etc so my code may have a smattering of these that are redundant):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer

Public Class FrmData
Private dsS As DataSet = New DataSet
Private adpS As SqlDataAdapter
Private builder As SqlCommandBuilder
Private bsource = New BindingSource

Private Sub FrmData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
          MyBase.Load

    Dim sqlS = "SELECT   [Data].[Date] AS [Date] ,
        [Data].[PaidBy] AS [Paid By] ,
        [Data].[PaidAmount] AS [Paid Amount (£)],
        [Data].[AmountLeft] AS [Amount Left (£)] 
        FROM [Data] WHERE [Data].[Name]= '" & strName & "'
        ORDER BY [Data].[Date] DESC"
    Dim adpS As SqlDataAdapter
    adpS = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlS, connection)
    builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adpS)
    Dim dTable As New DataTable

    bsource.DataSource = dTable
    bsource.EndEdit()
    adpS.Fill(dTable)
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dTable

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)

    Dim x As Integer = 0

    If dt.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("The table contains no changes to save.")
    Else
        Dim builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adpS)
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = adpS.Update(dt)
        If rowsAffected = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No rows were affected by the save operation.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " rows were affected by the save operation.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have no value for strName. Concatenating strings is not the way to build as SQL statement. Use Parameters to avoid errors and help prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, strName comes in from another form. The data in the grid is displaying correctly. I can edit it but it just doesn’t update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for SQL Server, right.  Try it like this.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I created a new project, table etc. It works, thanks so much I now have something I can work with. Again many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After two days working on this, I finally got it right for myself! Also, I had an eye on @ryguy72 codes as well. these are the steps you can take to get there:

Step 1: Drag and drop DataGridView into your form

Step 2: In the App.config add this between configuration:

```
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ehsanConnection" connectionString="Data Source=XXX 
         ; User= XX; Password= XXX"  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </connectionStrings>
```

Step 3: The code below shows how you can get the DataGridView programmatically right, it worked perfectly fine for me.

```
     Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
     Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
     Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
     Dim sDs As DataSet
     Dim sTable As DataTable

    Dim connStr As String = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ehsanConnection").ToString

    Dim connStri = New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [Ehsan].[dbo].[Data]"

    sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connStri)
    sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)

    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Data")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("Data")
    connStri.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Data")
```

The main point here was that I had to use [Ehsan].[dbo].[Data] not only the name of the table, "Data". Actually, it didn't work for me that way and it kept complaining!

Step 4: If you want to update your database after you changed some of the records in datagridview, use this code :

```
   sAdapter.Update(sDs.Tables(0))
```

Main important point is that: "you have to set a primary key in your table first otherwise it won't work!"

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. After using ryguy72's code below and fiddling around a bit I got it working. I found out, like you, about the primary key. It;s a bit different from VBA or maybe I've been using that for a long time and habits are hard to break!